# Make a empty lists and append all the sub-keys of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has sub dictionary like this:

```
d ={10L: {u'Owner Name': u'abc', u'Email': u'wa@gmail.com', u'Manager Name': u'jhon'}, 12L: {u'Owner Name': u'awdaw', u'Email': u'raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com', u'Manager Name': u'raghav'}}
```

So when I do `d[10][Owner Name]` I get `abc`. But this pattern repeats itself I mean each sub-dictionary have these same sub-keys and each sub-dictionary is of same length relatively. So, if I add few parameters in sub-dict with `id=10` then I will add same parameters to other keys.

Now, my question is everytime a item in my sub-dict increases I have to make a empty list and append its values to that list by:

```
def getcontacts():
    id = [10, 12]
    Owner_names = []
    Emails = []
    Manager_Names = []  # to add more columns just add an empty list
    for j in id:
        Owner_names.append(d[j]['Owner Name'])
        Emails.append(d[j]['Email'])
        Manager_names.append(d[j]['Manager Name'])  # append to list
    return Owner_names, Emails, Manager_Names

names, emails, managers = get_contacts()
```

At first I thought this is a good approach but as the items in my sub-dictionary are increasing I need to make a empty list and to append and return it.

Is there a way I could automate this process. So if I have a sub-key name `Product Name` my function could automatically create an empty list `Product_Names` and append it like `Product_names.append(d[j]['Product Name'])` and then return it when I call get contacts by:

`Owner_names, emails, Manager_Name, Product Names = get_contacts()`.

Is it possible where I could write a function which:

1. Count sub-keys in my dictionary and make empty list by putting `s` as post-fix.
2. Append the respective values to the list and add it to the return statement.

**Update**

Will the defaultdict solution will still be helpful if I want to have control over what values to use. Currently I am doing this:

```
for name, email, manager in zip(names, emails, managers):
         print name, email , manager
         message = message_template.substitute(PERSON_NAME=name.title(),MANAGER_NAME=manager.title())
```

Lets say I have two list:

```
l1 = [u'abc', u'awdaw']
l2 = [u'jhon', u'raghav']
for name1,name2 in zip(l1,l2):
    print name1, name2
```

But I cannot zip a dictionary for obvious reasons. How can the default dict help me in using which values I want to use. SO I I don't want to include `Owner_Name` I would just skip that in this line:

```
message = message_template.substitute(MANAGER_NAME=manager.title())
```

Comment: The answer by Bruno Desthuilliers will do the trick. If you don't necessarily need to work with dictionaries, you can also take a look at dataframes. `import pandas as pd`; `df = pd.DataFrame(d).T`

Comment: You need to look then at an ordereddict (look around for one). The reason being that a normal dict will return it's values/keys in an ordered you don't control (and you want this dynamic). But think about it... you're adding a key to the data dict and you want it as a return parameter but you're not asking your function where to put it!

Comment: "Will the defaultdict solution will still be helpful if I want to have control over what values to use" => well, yes of course why ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution: instead of returning a tuple of lists, return a dict of lists where keys are the subdicts keys and values the lists of collected values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_contacts():
    id = [10, 12]
    results = defaultdict(list)
    for j in id:
        obj = d[j]
        for key, value in obj.items():
            results[key].append(value)
    return results

results = get_contacts()
for k, v in results.items():
    print("{} : {}".format(k, v))
```

As a general rule: when you think you need "dynamic names", you really want a dict.

EDIT:

```
names, emails, managers = get_contacts()
for name, email, manager in zip(names, emails, managers):
    # ...
```

=>

```
results = get_contacts()
names, emails, managers = results["Owner Name"], results['Manager Name'], results["Email"]
for name, email, manager in zip(names, emails, managers):
    # ...
```

Comment: defaultdict. yes. better than mine :)

Comment: This would do. But the things is when I call get_contacts() I get separate lists. Using which I do. `for name, email, manager in zip(Owner_names, Emails, Manager_Names):` and then I call it like `message_template.substitute(PERSON_NAME=name.title(),MANAGER_NAME=manager.title())` . How can I do that using a default dict. Because I still want a control on the number of keys I use

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers could you see the update please

Comment: "But the things is when I call get_contacts() I get separate lists" => you still get separate lists. The only difference is that they are now named `results["Owner Name"]` instead of `names` etc... And nothing prevents you from binding them to whatever name you like, ie `names = results["Owner Name"]` (cf my edited answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
data ={10L: {u'Owner Name': u'abc', u'Email': u'wa@gmail.com', u'Manager Name': u'jhon'}, 
       12L: {u'Owner Name': u'awdaw', u'Email': u'raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com', u'Manager Name': u'raghav'}}

def get_contact(data, ids):
    ret_data = {}
    for i in ids:
        sub_data = data.get(i)
        for k in sub_data.keys():
            ret_data[k] = ret_data.get(k, [])
            ret_data[k].append(sub_data[k])

    # Doing this will have unordered results so one would have to
    # throw data into an OrderedDict (from a 3rd party lib like boltons)
    # return [ret_data[k] for k in ret_data.keys()]

    # so make sense to return the dict
    return ret_data
```

Udpate:
So you want the returned data to be ordered in a way you expect.
Well then you need to tell your "data" keys what order you expect them.

```
def get_contact(data, ids):
ret_data = {}
for i in ids:
    sub_data = data.get(i)
    for k in sub_data.keys():
        ret_data[k] = ret_data.get(k, [])
        ret_data[k].append(sub_data[k])

return [ret_data[k] for k in sorted(ret_data.keys())]
```

Comment: I also prefer to use the default dict but the issue is both you and  @Bruno Desthuilliers  return results in the form of dictionary. But what I further do in the script is that I zip lists: `for name, email, manager in zip(names, emails, managers):  ` and do this `message = message_template.substitute(PERSON_NAME=name.title(),MANAGER_NAME=manager.title())` this way I could have more control over which values I need. How could I do that in your dictionary

Comment: You're asking get_contacts to return you values from keys dynamically. You're not telling get_contacts what order you expect them to return to you in. A dict at least allows you to interrogate that structure. So either use an ordereddict or add an "orderby" key in your structure so that you can explicitly return what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

```
    d ={10: {'Owner Name': 'abc', 'Email': 'wa@gmail.com', 'Manager Name': 'jhon'}, 
        12: {'Owner Name': 'awdaw', 'Email': 'raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com', 'Manager Name': 'raghav'}}
    from collections import defaultdict
    def get_contacts():
        data = defaultdict(list)
        for key, val in d.items():
            for key1, val1 in val.items():
                data[key1 + 's'].append(val1)
        return data.values()
    names, emails, managers = get_contacts()
    >>>print(names, emails, managers)
       (['abc', 'awdaw'],['wa@gmail.com', 'raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com'],
        ['jhon', 'raghav'])
```

Comment: Dicts are unordered so you cannot rely on the ordering of `dict.values()`. Also, returning values only means you have to update the LHS of the `get_contacts()` call each time something is added to the dub dicts.